# Software to track donations and donors for a European non-profit?

Tags: windows, web-apps, donation

I work for a non-profit which is based in Italy and France. We have donors from countries in North America and Europe. Right now, we have an old Microsoft Access app, custom written by one of our guys some years ago, that we use to keep track of donors and donations. We use some of the most basic features like:

- Reporting which give us overviews of the data (e.g. how many donations have we received from which countries)
- Microsoft Word templates which allow us to bang out "Thank You" letters.

The biggest custom piece of the application is all the VB macros, which do a lot of simple logic (for tax purposes, for example). Is there any software out there which could possibly meet our use case? We've simply outgrown Access's data limits.

Answer (score 3):

AbleOrganizer would be a possible solution.

- It is built in Drupal using CRM Core and CRM Core Donation.
- The system has strong content management tools and can be directly integrated into your website.
- It has strong reporting tools, including overview reports, source reporting, online donation page reports, LYBUNT, SYBUNT, and a whole list of other things you might find useful.
- It also has features for events, petitions, volunteer activity, and an API for developing your own features.

You can download a copy from Drupal.org at https://drupal.org/project/ableorganizer. You can also download just the modules contained in the distro to use as part of your sites, there's nothing special about AO that forces you to use this distro. All the features are Features that can be turned on and off in each site.

Answer (score 1):

[CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/) is a great option. Here are some features relevant to your case:

- Many languages available
- Tracks donors and donations
- Accepts donations directly online
- Extensive reporting
- Integrated workflow for donation thank-you processing